# 403 error through Apache2.4 Directory Alias: what's wrong?

Tags: apache2, alias

I ask for some help to keep hairs on my head :D
More seriously, I tried a lot "solutions" found on different posts on different forums, without any result so I need a clean and fresh point of view...

So : I run a JEE application with Apache 2.4 and Tomcat 9 with mod_jk.
To avoid to store heavy content like video in my JEE webapp I created a directory on my server dedicated to some static content.
To do that I try to set a directory alias in my apache vhost, but I get 403 error.

- You will find my vhost below, with an alias from /video to /etc/mondir/video (I tried with or without ending /)
- I tried a lot of Directory directives without result
- Apache2 owned the targeted directory trough www-data user
- I also tried to declare the directory alias in etc/apache2/mods-available/alias.conf : not better.

I have no more idea and find no mode idea on the Internet.

Could you please give me some clue? help? advise?
Thank a lot !

```xml
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName mondomaine.com
    ServerAlias www.mondomaine.com
    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    
    #DocumentRoot /var/www
    DocumentRoot /etc/mondir/
    
    <Directory /etc/mondir/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    
    #Add acces to static ressource in /etc/mondir
    Alias "/video"  "/etc/mondir/video"
    Alias "/moncontext/video"  "/etc/mondir/video"
    
    <Directory "/etc/mondir/video">
        #Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        #AllowOverride None
        #Order allow,deny
        #Allow from all
    
        #Options FollowSymlinks
        #AllowOverride None
        #Require all granted
    
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mondomaine\.com
    RewriteRule   ^video/(.*)  /video/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule   ^video(.*)  /video/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule   ^moncontext/(.*)  /moncontext/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule   ^moncontext(.*)  /moncontext/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule   ^(.*)  /moncontext/$1  [L,QSA]
    
    
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mondomaine.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mondomaine.com/privkey.pem
    
    JkMount /moncontext/* ajp13_worker

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The good directive is "Require all granted"
But, above all, the problem and the solution is on mod_rewrite side.
By default, the rewrite doesnt reach the filesystem, only URI.
Rewrite rule must have the Pass Through option (PT flag) to be seen by the Dir Alias.

More information on mod_rewrite documentation : it's written and simple if you know where to read.

Thank all,